# Is there a way to modify module path and added modules of a programmatic JShell instance?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell, module-path

I'm trying to run some Java code at run-time through a JShell instance I created using the [JShell API](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/JShell.html). To demonstrate my problem, I'm going to share my simple code.

With my current setup I have a directory called *lib* that has the MySQL Java driver: *mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar*.

Launching JShell via command tool and adding the needed module as:

```
jshell --module-path lib --add-modules mysql.connector.java
```

and then loading the mysql driver works for me :

```
jshell> Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
$1 ==> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@42f93a98
```

---

I've created a similar Java 9 module with `module-info.java` as:

```
module example.loadmysql {
    requires java.sql;
    requires mysql.connector.java;
    requires jdk.jshell;
}
```

***src/example/loadmysql/Runner.java*** as :

```
package example.loadmysql;

import jdk.jshell.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // this works because this module requires mysql.connector.java
        System.out.println(Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance());

        JShell js = JShell.create();
        String code = ""
            + "try {"
            + "    Class.forName(\"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\").newInstance();"
            + "} catch (Exception e) {"
            + "    System.out.println(e.toString());"
            + "}";
        js.eval(code);
    }
}
```

After building/packaging:

```
java -p lib -m example.loadmysql
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@6a4f787b
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

---

It's clear that even though the *example.loadmysql* module requires the mysql connector, the created JShell instance doesn't. So it can't find the class.

Any ideas on how to programmatically add modules to a JShell instance, so it works like the direct JShell coding example?

***UPDATE*** - I've figured out how to set the module path:

```
String modulePath = System.getProperty("jdk.module.path");
js.eval("System.setProperty(\"jdk.module.path\", \""
    + modulePath + "\");");
```

But that's not quite enough. I still have add the needed module somehow.

Comment: Did you try putting [`addToClassPath`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/JShell.html#addToClasspath-java.lang.String-) before `eval`?

Comment: I could add to classpath and that seems to work. Though it's not in the spirit Java 9 and using modules! I'm not sure that if the mysql connector is eventually converted into a module if the classpath method will still work. I might do it this way if there's no other solution though! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use [`addToClassPath`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/JShell.html#addToClasspath-java.lang.String-) before `eval` in your code as:

```
JShell js = JShell.create();
js.addToClasspath("path/to/add/to/the/classpath");
String code = ""
        + "try {"
        + "    Class.forName(\"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\").newInstance();"
        + "} catch (Exception e) {"
        + "    System.out.println(e.toString());"
        + "}";
js.eval(code);
```

> The specified path is added to the end of the *classpath used in
>   `eval()`*. Note that the *unnamed package* is not accessible from the
>   package in which `eval(String)` code is placed.

It seems from the documentation that the state of JShell returned post `eval` executes the code based on the classpath, hence in order to add any further dependencies to it, you would need to add it to the classpath using the same method.

---

In your case I am guessing here though as you do so, the *mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar* would ideally be treated to as an *automatic module* present on the classpath and hence the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` would be accessible.

---

***Update*** :- Exploring further I think a better way to achieve this could be though trying to use [`Jshell.Builder`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/JShell.Builder.html) and its option [`compilerOptions`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/JShell.Builder.html#compilerOptions-java.lang.String...-) to create an instance with default compiling options somewhat like(not tested) -

```
JShell js = JShell.builder()
                 .compilerOptions("--module-path lib","--add-modules mysql.connector.java").build();
String code = ""
    + "try {"
    + "    Class.forName(\"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\").newInstance();"
    + "} catch (Exception e) {"
    + "    System.out.println(e.toString());"
    + "}";
js.eval(code);
```

Comment: Thank you! This method will work for now. I just have to keep track of both module path and class path. I would prefer handling it the Java 9 way with modules, but if that's not possible I can just stick to this. I'll accept your answer for now I suppose!

Comment: @DylanJohnson ya doesn't seem to be an ideal way but seems like the `eval` by itself uses a classpath to evaluate the code provided.

Comment: @DylanJohnson Though not tested. But probably the edit should be a cleaner way to help here.

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately I get IllegalArgumentExceptions. I can't seem to find much documentation on this compilerOptions method either. Like which flags are legal! Thank you though; this gives me some more ideas to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/env` command to add modules, see help:

```
/env [-class-path <path>] [-module-path <path>] [-add-modules <modules>] ...
|   view or change the evaluation context
```

Details:

```
jshell> /help context
|  
|  context
|  
|  These options configure the evaluation context, they can be specified when
|  jshell is started: on the command-line, or restarted with the commands /env,
|  /reload, or /reset.
|  
|  They are:
|   --class-path <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
|       A list of directories, JAR archives,
|       and ZIP archives to search for class files.
|       The list is separated with the path separator
|       (a : on unix/linux/mac, and ; on windows).
|   --module-path <module path>...
|       A list of directories, each directory
|       is a directory of modules.
|       The list is separated with the path separator
|       (a : on unix/linux/mac, and ; on windows).
|   --add-modules <modulename>[,<modulename>...]
|       root modules to resolve in addition to the initial module.
|       <modulename> can also be ALL-DEFAULT, ALL-SYSTEM,
|       ALL-MODULE-PATH.
|   --add-exports <module>/<package>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*
|       updates <module> to export <package> to <target-module>,
|       regardless of module declaration.
|       <target-module> can be ALL-UNNAMED to export to all
|       unnamed modules. In jshell, if the <target-module> is not
|       specified (no =) then ALL-UNNAMED is used.
|  
|  On the command-line these options must have two dashes, e.g.: --module-path
|  On jshell commands they can have one or two dashes, e.g.: -module-path
```

Comment: I believe OP is trying to achieve the same using java code. Otherwise the `--module-path` and `--add-modules` works fine as mentioned in the question as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I've found through my testing that you can't evaluate a /env command programmatically. Only from directly working inside JShell. Good idea though!

Comment: @DylanJohnson Yes, this does not work indeed :(. If i read the documentation carefully, my impression is however that it should work (see update). No mention that `JShell` does not support this functionality. Needs some more investigation ...