# Java library to execute/evaluate code like a REPL console

Tags: java, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

Does Java ecosystem have a library that allow to pass a `String` and evaluate and execute that code?

```
eval("String value = text.split(\",\")[0]")
```

There is something like this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html

Comment: The JShell tool

Comment: BeanShell might be another option (but haven’t used it for a while now): https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell

Comment: @shmosel @Slaw the `JShell` allows to use imported classes?

Comment: Yes, you can import classes. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/jshell/external-code.html#GUID-D0BED087-AD44-4048-B37D-054308C64390

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399783/is-there-a-way-to-modify-module-path-and-added-modules-of-a-programmatic-jshell if you're more interested in using JShell programmatically.